# How can I snap edges to grid lines?

Tags: edges, snapping, loop

I am very new to Blender and I'm having some trouble with grid snapping. 
I have absolute grid snapping enabled. If I select an edge or edge loop and attempt to snap to grid, it snaps in the correct increments, but not exactly to the grid lines. However if I select a singe vertex it snaps to the grid lines perfectly. What am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Scott.

Answer (score 4):

*Snap > Increment* with *✓ Absolute Grid Snap* seems to work fine.

To have more precision

- switch to Ortho view (*View > Perspective/Orthographic*, <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>)
- use a top/side/view *(View > Viewpoint > Top*,  <kbd>~</kbd> )

[image]

[image]