# How to create an object by dimensions

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have taught myself a few basic things in Blender using Youtube video tutorials but still am "all thumbs" when trying to work out how to create an object (for MSFS2020) consisting of a dock used by float planes.

1. I have created a motor vehicle tyre-like object but not added a material using the TORUS mesh object (very easy).
2. I have downloaded and imported some 3D objects to try to work out how it is done but still I am scratching my head.

It would be great if I could watch a video tutorial which someone can point me to which shows how to create a similar looking model (doesn't have to be a dock but similar in shape to a dock) or give me some easily understood ideas.
I have included part of an image showing the type of object I would like to create in Render.

An example would be to create a 'cube' which like a regular plank of wood. I see that I can drag the vertices of a cube to represent a plant of wood but how do you ensure all sides are parallel to each other ie that the plank is as think one end as the other. I am thinking for this object all that is required is a number of 'planks of timber' placed in correct places or joined together.
Thanks

*[added later]*
I just found a youtube video tutorial how to make a wood plank but still nee to know how to create to a particular dimension eg 3.6 metres long, 200mm wide, 50mm think. Also I will have to create a number of different 'plank's and then duplicate some and attach all the parts into the dock. [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDCN27-LJ1w)
[image: image of dock showing parts]

Comment: Hello and welcome, i highly recommended you to start with the fundamentals and after that look for some Hard surface modeling... Some of the fundamentals are the use a mirror modifier to help you make half of an object and the other half will be automatic. [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) you will find some fundamentals to check. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware of those youtube tutorials. I had watched 1 or 2 different tutorials and learned much about some of the hot keys, tools available etc. Wow there is far more to learn than I think I need. Some of the tools I feel are for features I would never use for simple unanimated objects such as a dock which probably has only 5 different 'parts'. Yes the tutorials (probably) explain every feature and tool available I just wished there were tutorials how to create simple objects and I will use the first few and try to use the other tutorial I found and try and use intuition.

Comment: Hello :). This should be rather easy, could you please add more images to show the dock shape? And do you want a traditional [timber dock](http://www.supercub.org/photopost/data//528/medium/274P1010291.jpg) or a [modern one](https://www.jetdock.com/uploads/Seaplane-1.jpg)?

Comment: Not trying to kill anyone's buzz, but can someone explain why this seemingly too broad question that basically asks for a tutorial already got two upvotes, whereas more than two-thirds of the questions on the main page have no votes at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's asking for a referral, and is too broad in general (I used the 'Needs more details' option).

Comment: Excuse me I am NOT asking for anyone to do anything. I would just like a tutorial which doesn't not include EVERY possible tool hot key etc etc etc just so that I can have a go at creating something simple. I could not differentiate in the tutorials what was applicable to my simple project, as they are very comprehensive. My head was thumping half way through and at the end remembered  maybe 5 things. Of course practice makes perfect I know (I once was an analyst/programmer both for applications and html so not dumb!) Blender is the most complex application I have ever encountered.

Comment: @joachim - I personnally upvoted as it’s a question from someone who is new to Blender and doesn’t know the terms to ask how to achieve the (simple when you know how) basic operations to create “planks” to their required dimensions and position them. It showed what they already achieved and what they are struggling with. IMO it wasn’t asking for a tutorial - more for pointers how to get started and links to existing tutorials and information that’s already out there. From that perspective this seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. Lack of votes on other questions is a good point.

Comment: But asking for tutorials is explicitly off-topic on all of the Stack Exchange network (see  [this thread](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/65455), which can be found through the [Help]). The problem is not asking for someone to do something, which is implicit in any question (in reply to John's comment).

Comment: @JohnArnold Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. If you could [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: If the question was short and just requesting a tutorial then I’d agree. However, it’s it would be great if I could watch a video tutorial “ or give me some easily understood ideas”. I do think the general gist of the question is broadly in line with the site - certainly the original intention was. I think maybe an edit to the question would be helpful to rephrase it to remove the tutorial bit - and the question stands on its own without that.

Comment: @duarte I don’t think the OP is asking for a tutorial or lengthy procedure - just some pointers as to how to scale a cube to specific dimensions and then how to duplicate and position that to create the desired structure. I’ll add a specific answer myself when I get the chance but the current answer covers it.

Comment: @RichSedman could you rephrase it to conform more to our rules? If you do feel free to poke me i the comments, I'll be glad to reopen

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos TBH, don't bother. I think the current answer just about solves the problem and hopefully John finds this helpful. It does concern me that new users do all they can to ask a question and then get knocked back and the question is closed. It seems quite harsh and unwelcoming to me and IMO would be better to suggest an edit and give time to respond. Closure seems final to a new user (but I know to you it's just a temporary state if the question can be fixed). I know you've got a lot of work moderating the site and I suppose a swift closure gets it off your list.

Comment: Closure sounding like a permanent thing for new users is a problem we deal with daily, hence why I always tend to leave a message in that regards with the specific wording "on hold" instead. I can see this seems like a senior user struggling with first steps, so I intentionally withheld immediatly acting on it until Jachym's  satisfactory answer popped up, which current seems to answer the OP reasonably well. There are also several duplicates around one could point the OP to, so all in all it could have been closed for several other reasons

Comment: @JohnArnold For the OP if something still feels unanswered or unclear feel free to post new questions about it

Comment: Well here we go again. Blender is frustrating me no end. I try and learn using tutorials but cannot duplicate what I see and hear in the tutorial.  Immediately what some to mind is how to create an object by dimensions. I add a cube (mesh object) and in tutorials pops up a panel displaying Location, Rotation, Scale yet in the tutorials it also shows DIMENSIONS. I have 'googled' Blender dimensions, looked in Help, looked in the html manual and NO WHERE is mentioned about dimensions. Also looked around the Blender workspace and could not find how to display dimensions so that they can be entered

Comment: Hi John. The Blender interface can take some getting used to - so I understand your frustration. Also, it’s changed a lot over the last few years and so online examples are often different. To fit in with the rules here, ask multiple simple questions - this way they can be individually answered or marked as ‘duplicate’ (so you get someone else’s answer anyway). For the dimensions, press ‘N’ while in viewport and you should see dimensions in the panel that pops out of the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dock should be rather easy to make.

1. *Add > Mesh > Cube* and enter the plank dimensions (3600x200x50)
2. Then go *Apply > Scale*
3. Now add the *Array modifier* (to duplicate your planks)
4. Use the same principles to create the rails and the bottom floating part

*Planks made using Array modifier*
[image]

[image]

*Bottom part*
[image]

*Final model*
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks yes I have now grasped part of your excellent 'videos' and the other parts look great especially how to set the dimensions of each piece of timber. The youtube tutorial I referred to shows how to create a plank of timber but was using an old version of Blender and I have now worked out accidentally with a bit of intuition which is different in old versions.  Yes the dock basically consists of an elongated box with a top and bottom and with planks across the top as you have shown. Such a lot of tutorialsl tell you what is available but not what it could be used for.

Comment: Glad it helped :). Feel free to ask more questions if you get stuck anywhere, 3D modeling can feel overwhelming.

Comment: My first thoughts were to create separate objects for the planks along the sides, planks for the ends, timber slats for the walkway along the top etc and then position each separate object together to make the dock. I am not sure if this would be the correct or best method. I am not interested very much in 3d texture eg the actual difference in height of the grain in the timber, nor am I interested in how light falls on the object as it will never be seen close up.

Comment: Thanks again Jachym. I see you have added more 'tutorial'. I will look at that again tomorrow and get stuck into my project although one last question and I am assuming this is true -

Comment: Ask away, that's why this site exists :)

Comment: Next morning. I now see that you suggest building the dock with a large rectangular shape of the dimensions of the dock and then adding the planks to the top which IMHO is the easiest method and so that is what I will do. Lots of 'tricks' to learn.   Can I add lines to aid placement of objects in the correct position eg like adding a grid in an image editor? Maybe I need to learn how to place repeated (such as car tyres along the sides) objects in an array?

Comment: Hi :). You can snap to grid increments (as did I when modeling it). This should help: [How can I snap edges to grid lines?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145924/78972)